# Joint distribution of two equal random variables

Tags: self-study, random-variable, joint-distribution

Suppose that X2 is continuously distributed with density g(x2) > 0 on [0, 1). Let X1 = X2. Derive the joint distribution function F (x1, x2) and the marginal density fX1 (x1).

I'm not sure about this question, does f(x1,x2)=g(x2) since x1 and x2 are perfectly correlated?

Comment: Joint density with respect to which measure?

Comment: @Xi'an A joint density is not requested ;-).  Jacy: you are given the marginal density of $X_1$ because it must be the density of $X_2.$ Only the joint distribution function needs to be worked out, which by definition is $$F(x,y)=\Pr(X_1\le x\text{ and }X_2\le y) = \Pr(X_2\le x\text{ and }X_2\le y) = \Pr(X_2\le\min(x,y)).$$ What aspect of that calculation do you need help with?

Comment: @whuber Thanks! I see for the distribution function now, but we still need joint density function right? since we need to calculate marginal density fX1(x1),we should first get the density and then integrate by x2?

Comment: The point of the comment by @Xi'an was that there is no density relative to the usual (Borel) measure.  This is a *singular* distribution: all its probability is concentrated on a region that has no area at all (namely, a line).  That's why you aren't asked to compute a density function.